# Workflow in SP designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I'm having problems when using SharePoint Designer 2013, this problem is , when i create more than one workflow to the same list , if another workflow start for example to create list item to my list , the main workflow stop .
my Question is how to solve this problems and if any way to do it ?with thanks for you developers .

Comment: if you share your workflows, we can take a look into them...

Answer (score 1):

While researching for this issue, I found a link that shows how to use secondary workflow. However, that article applies to SharePoint Designer 2007. Here is the link for the same: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-secondary-workflow-6B77FFD5-9AD6-4C20-B5A4-D686E2DEAFC2 I am not sure whether this would work with 2013 but you can try and check.